Rails: nested namespace produces a weird path to a partial, resulting a MissingTemplate error
I have an ActiveRecord model named Book, and a model named Book::Author. An author has many books through the Book::Authorship model (one-to-many association).
Off-topic:

 The reason to put the Author model under the Book namespace is that I might want to have another author model (e.g. the Post::Author) which is completely unrelated to the Book::Author. With a namespace I can clearly show the relationship, e.g.: example.com/books/authors explicitly states that these are the authors that wrote books (and not posts or anything else).

In my app only administrators can create/update/delete Books and Authors. So I've created a separated namespace Admin for the controllers and the views for the administrators only.
In the routes.rb file I have:
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  # These are for the regular users:
  # only #index and #show actions are defined in the respective controllers:
  namespace :books do
    resources :authors, only: %i[index show]
  end
  resources :books, only: %i[index show]

  # These are for the admins only:
  # all CRUD methods are defined in the respective controllers:
  namespace :admin do
    namespace :books do
      resources :authors
    end

    resources :books
  end
  resources :admin

  root "books#index"
end

Then I've created the Admin::Books::AuthorsController controller:

/app/controllers/admin/books/authors_controller.rb

I would expect that the view path follows the same path pattern:

/app/views/admin/books/authors/_index.html.erb for the index;
/app/views/admin/books/authors/_author.html.erb for the partial.

Unfortunately, it doesn't: the index page does work, but it can't find the _author.html.erb partial.
Here's how I'm trying to render the list of authors in the /app/views/admin/books/authors/_index.html.erb:
  <% @books_authors.each do |book_author| %>
    <%= render book_author %>
  <% end %>

Which gives the following error:

ActionView::MissingTemplate in Admin::Books::Authors#index
Missing partial admin/books/books/author/_author with {...}.

There are two “books” in the path... but why?
The code above works only with an explicit path to the template:
  <% @books_authors.each do |book_author| %>
    <%= render "admin/books/authors/author", book_author: book_author %>
  <% end %>

Which I don't like, since it breaks the convention over configuration paradigm. I don't want to manually type a path in every view under the Admin::Books:: namespace.
I'm looking for a way to achieve the desired functionality without using an explicit path. How I can tell Rails to not include “books” twice in the path when it's looking for a partial?

You controller is namespaced Admin::Books and your model is Books::Author, together you get double "books" path. The logic roughly looks like this:
[
  File.dirname(Admin::Books::AuthorsController.new.lookup_context.prefixes.first),
  Books::Author.new.to_partial_path
].join("/")

#=> "admin/books/books/authors/author"

lookup_context is something you could modify (probably not a good idea):
# app/controllers/admin/books/authors_controller.rb

def index
  lookup_context.prefixes = ["admin/books", "application"]
  @books_authors = Books::Author.all
end

Another way would be to drop one of the Books namespaces:
# either change your controller
class Admin::AuthorsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @books_authors = Books::Author.all
  end
end

# or model, what if someone writes a book and a post?
class Admin::Books::AuthorsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @books_authors = Author.joins(:books)
  end
end

Keeping your models flat is a popular way of sticking to conventions, no namespaces - no problems:
BookAuthor
PostAuthor


Thank you. I (almost) made the same conclusion, but I had to confirm it just to make sure that I’m not missing something. I had difficulties with namespaced models right from the beginning, but I found a solution here, which is a rather awkward one, since you had to (again!) manually type classes and table names to get it work.
It looks Rails indeed doesn’t work well with namespaced models, so I’ll probably drop them.

just to add as another option, you could also redefine to_partial_path on your models, which I think would be a better solution: def to_partial_path "authors/author" end

thanks, it works, but monkey-patching the to_partial_path (as well as the lookup_context) method seems too "hacky" to me. At the end of the day I've decided to embrace the KISS principle, e.g. to not use nested namespaces at all.


There are two “books” in the path... but why?

Namespaces of your models do have impact on default partial paths.
You can investigate the way it's being defined here:
https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/main/actionview/lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb#L76

I'm looking for a way to achieve the desired functionality without using an explicit path.

In order not to use an explicit path you need to get rid of your models namespaces.
Let it just be Book and Author. Check example here:
https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#why-associations-questionmark
And I guess you don't need separate table to store one-to-many association (in your case books.author_id should do the job).

Thank you for you input. “Books” and “authors” are just fictional concepts to illustrate the point. In the real project I will mostly use a many-to-many relationship. That’s why I am using a third model Authorship in the example.
